# Wav to mp3 for soundtouch

Tags: objective-c

I want to use the sound touch library on mp3 files, the problem is that it work only on wav files, there is any way to do convert in objective-c from mp3 to wav ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, and if there is a way to do that, it's probably a very expensive operation (meaning it'll take some time and cpu).

Are they static files? Could you convert them prior to adding them to your Xcode-project (instead of converting them on-the-fly, as you suggest)?

Comment: for using this library(sound touch) i need wav files so it is not possible to do it in any other way

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what kind of files are they? Are they recordings or downloaded files (from within the app)? Or could you convert them to .wav-files before building your app?

Comment: they are files from the ipod library

Comment: Mhmm, that indeed makes it some harder. I'll search for such a tool right now. I suppose you could cache the results (so you only have to convert a song once, then it's cached so it doesn't have to convert it again when you play the song a second time).

Comment: Here's another question + solution that does exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478030/iphone-convert-mp3-to-wav

Comment: Well, the question is specifically targeted on the iPhone, so I suppose so :p! Just to remind you, if it works, you **need** to cache the results. iPhones normally aren't capable of performing such expensive operations, so you need to cache the results. Also, I'ld recommend you showing some sort of progress-bar / indicator so your users don't think it's freezing, hanging or crashing :)!