# alarm iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, uilocalnotification, avplayer

I'm trying to make alarm in my app. I made UILocalNotification and it works fine. But i need to set a mp3 song as a sound of my notification and it is not working

Here is some code

```
    NSString *filePath = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"personal.mp3"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",filePath);

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    localNotif.fireDate = alarmPicker.date;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Alarm";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.soundName = filePath;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    //localNotif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

Should I add framework or what i should do? right now it is not playing my mp3. Thanks

Comment: were you able to play to mp3 in your app? ( == does the mp3 itself work? )

Comment: @Tomen yeah. In another controller I play mp3 files well

Comment: is the .mp3 song having less than 30 sec duration? because 30 sec is the maximum sound duration supported by UIlocalNotification

Comment: @Krrish it is 2 minutes long. Is it way to cut it programatically?

Comment: @Dmitriy please see my answer. I just now googled your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UILocation notification does not support .mp3 these are the files supported

> Because custom alert sounds are played by the iOS system-sound
>   facility, they must be in one of the following audio data formats:
>
> Linear PCM
>
> MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
>
> µLaw
>
> aLaw
>  You can package the audio data in
>   an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in Xcode, add the sound file to your
>   project as a nonlocalized resource of the application bundle.

Please see the answer for this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716966/setting-sounds-for-local-notifications-on-a-3g-iphone-running-ios4)

Also see this [Preparing Custom Alert Sounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

**EDIT :ADDING ANSWER FOR DURATION**

> You can inspect a sound to determine its data format by opening it in
>   QuickTime Player and choosing Show Movie Inspector from the Movie
>   menu.
>
> Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound
>   is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

You can use Audio editor/converter to trim your song

[Switch](http://www.nch.com.au/switch/index.html)

[WavePad](http://www.nch.com.au/wavepad/index.html)

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Is it a way to convert mp3 to wav programatically in iphone?

Comment: check this link, this may be of help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478030/iphone-convert-mp3-to-wav

Comment: i think the duration is the problem cause mp3 file is working for me as long as it's less than 30 seconds for the soundName property

Comment: Yeah, I also had similar experience. If the mp3 file duration is less than 30 it will work